# How to use locks to ensure a method is only run a set number of times simultaneously

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, synchronization, locking

I know in Java, to ensure a segment of code is only run once at a time per thread, one simply uses the `synchronized` keyword. I.e.,

```
synchronized (getClass()) {
   // expensive work
}
```

However, what I'd rather do is only perform the expensive work while enough RAM is available. I.e., lets say I have 10 threads going and in the `expensive work` section of the code, it takes up 50 MBs of RAM. Lets say I do a calculation based on the Maximum memory the JVM can use and realize that I could run 5 of those threads at the same time safely.

So, how could I use `Locks` or `Concurrency` or `.wait()/.notify()` properly to ensure that the `expensive work` is only running that set number of times?

I hope my question makes sense. I have looked into [Locks](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/ejb/Lock.html) as well as [ReentrantLock](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/ReentrantLock.html) but I actually found the example to not work. In their example, it seemed like each separate thread created an instance of `lock` when in my case, I have multiple separate, independent threads going on at once and they aren't aware of each other.

Can anyone give an example, or give a link to an example where you use Concurrency/Locks to satisfy this scenario?

I need the solution to be Java 6 compatible.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> So, how could I use Locks or Concurrency or .wait()/.notify() properly to ensure that the expensive work is only running that set number of times?

The [`Semaphore`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Semaphore.html) is taylor made for this sort of thing.  It has a certain number of permits and a thread will block unless a permit is available.

To quote from the [javadocs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Semaphore.html):

> A counting semaphore. Conceptually, a semaphore maintains a set of permits. Each acquire() blocks if necessary until a permit is available, and then takes it. Each release() adds a permit, potentially releasing a blocking acquirer. However, no actual permit objects are used; the Semaphore just keeps a count of the number available and acts accordingly.

Something like the following code should work:

```
// only allow 5 threads to do the expensive work at the same time
private final Semaphore semaphore = new Semaphore(5, true /* fairness */);
...
// this will block if there are already 5 folks doing the expensive work
semaphore.acquire();
try {
   doExpensiveWork();
} finally {
   // always do the release in a try/finally to ensure the permit gets released
   // even if it throws
   semaphore.release();
}
```

Comment: Great! Should the semaphore variable be declared in the parent thread (and thus made `volatile` and `static`)?

Comment: I'd make it private final to the class you are trying to protect.  If you are trying to protect a `static` method then it should be `static` to the class.  You don't need to make it `volatile` and I wouldn't declare it in the thread.  The class should protect itself.

Comment: If you want multiple instances of a class to be protected then you'll need to make the semaphore static as well.

Comment: Thanks trying now. I'm doing this to help figure out dynamically how many permits to create `int maxThreadsForProcessing = (int) Runtime.getRuntime().maxMemory() / 1024 / 1024 / 70;` And testing now

Comment: It appears to have worked! Although, figuring out the precise # of locks to give each machine as a function on memory will be a little bit of an art. But I like this new tool :)